# Error #CS0738 'Notification' does not implement interface member 'IJob.Execute(IJobExecutionContext)'. 'Notification.Execute(IJobExecutionContext)'

Tags: c#, quartz.net, quartz, ijobfactory

```
using System;
using Quartz;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace hatirlaticiapp
{
    public class Notification : IJob
    {
        public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {
            JobDataMap data = context.JobDetail.JobDataMap;
            Task task = (Task)data["Task"];
            task.OnNotificationStarted(task, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

For this line of code I am getting such a warning.

ERROR :

> Error CS0738  'Notification' does not implement interface member
> 'IJob.Execute(IJobExecutionContext)'.
> 'Notification.Execute(IJobExecutionContext)' cannot implement
> 'IJob.Execute(IJobExecutionContext)' because it does not have the
> matching return type of 'Task'.

EDIT 1 : add my scheduling code

```cs
public class NotificationController : IController<Task>
{
    ISchedulerFactory schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
    IScheduler scheduler;

    public NotificationController()
    {            
        scheduler = schedulerFactory.GetScheduler();
        scheduler.Start();
    }
}
```

I am getting this error here too

ERROR :
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Quartz.IScheduler>' to 'Quartz.IScheduler'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Please help me ...

Comment: Show us your scheduling code

Comment: I've edit the answer and added the scheduler. please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be beneficial to look at https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/tutorial/index.html as it looks like some of your code is written for Version 2.2 but the error messages would suggest you are using Version 3.

In particular your second error may be because you are missing awaits, ie

```
  scheduler = schedulerFactory.GetScheduler();
  scheduler.Start();
```

should be

```
  scheduler = await schedulerFactory.GetScheduler();
  await scheduler.Start();
```

Also your first signature should be

```
  public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
```

and presumably you need to use `await` in the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Read the whole exception, at the end it says

`... because it does not have the matching return type of 'Task'.`

Change the return from `void` to `Task`.

Comment: To be clear, you changed 'void Execute' to 'Task Execute` and returned the `Task` being worked on? If you tried that, add it to your post. There is no charge for typing in more information. Just keep the information relevant.

Comment: Yes, I changed ‘void execute’ to ‘Task Execute’ and return task. But repeat error. I am getting the same error again.